# removing a controller name from url

Tags: codeigniter, routes

Am trying to remove a controller name in codeigniter form this,

`localhost/teekle/loggedin/info`.

to

`localhost/teekle/info`

I've tried the following code in my rooute.php file but nothing happened.

`$route['info'] = 'loggedin/info';`

But i just cant figure out a way to do so, can anyone help please?

Comment: That is right, something else is overriding it. What else is in your routes.php?

Comment: No, nothing is overiding it, it works if i browse to the url,  localhost/teekle/loggedin/info. but i thought it was supposed to automatically be like that? if i tried opening the page,  localhost/teekle/loggedin/info.

Comment: Where is your CodeIgniter `index.php` file located? `localhost` or `localhost/teekle/`?

Comment: @Daniel that is the point, something is screwing it up. The way your routing is set up that should be pointing to your base_url/info NOT base_url/loggedin/info. The latter should still work, but the first one should too.

Answer (score 0):

What is your config base url set to?

From your example I would guess it should be

`$config['base_url']    = 'http://localhost:8888/teekle/';`

If this is not set correctly it can cause issues. As a few other users have said what you have in your routes.php file should work.

Also, check that your .htaccess file for removing the index.php is correct, try appending /teekle/ if its not there.